# When $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are disjoint sets in Y?

Tags: general-topology

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets in X, $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are closed sets in $Y$.
When $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are disjoint sets in $Y$?
Thanks for any help you.

Comment: Is not the $f$ a 1-1 map otherwise this is false take for instance whole $X$ going to the same $y \in Y$ ?

Comment: f is one to one, onto and continuous.

Comment: When f is one - one for disjointness and open/closed map (takes open sets to open sets and similarly closed sets to closed sets) for closedness. So I think one-one and open will suffice.

Comment: @DiffeoR, I think the idea is to find a topological concept weaker than than injectivity which nonetheless implies disjointness of $f(A)$ and $f(B)$.

Comment: Ah continuous works other way round with inverses..here closedness will work.

Comment: You mean stronger, how can adding constraints be weaker ?

Comment: With your conditions you can say the same thing by picking up disjoint closed sets from range and looking at the preimages which would be closed and disjoint under the conditions you specify in the comment.

Comment: I would like to correct my comment : f is one-one and closed map will work and not open map.  As I just realized not all open maps are closed maps. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you need two conditions on $f$ :

For disjointness : $f$ has to be one-one.

For closed sets to go to closed sets : $f$ has to be a closed map.

---

If one wants a similar thing to happen when picking up disjoint closed sets from range, then we need : one - one for disjointness, continuous to make preimages closed, and ontoness to be able to pick up arbitrary closed sets in the range space.